# Why does Biden associate his campaign with characters that lost their popularity long ago?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

Biden recently appeared in a [fundraising event](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-68685608) with Obama and Bill Clinton. Both of the co-hosts saw their popularity drop after their term in office. Obama is mostly remembered for all the failed promises while Clinton in recent times has accumulated a long track record of negative appearances. During his wife campaign he was frequently pointed out as someone too close to big business and eventually he was credited with harming her campaign. Then he participated to an [event](https://znsbahamas.com/clinton-blair-and-bankman-fried-in-panel-discussion-at-ftx-salt-conference/) with Sam Bankman-Fried.

The analysts working for Biden should know well the current situation. Why did Biden chose to host an event with them anyway? Didn't he consider that the association might backfire?

Comment: It's an older poll, but I don't think the figures support the claims:  "Former president Barack Obama remains one of the most popular public figures among voters, a 2022 NBC News poll finds. ¶Fifty-one percent of voters surveyed have a very positive or somewhat positive view of Obama"    (That's higher than both Biden and Trump)

Comment: @JamesK Looks like a state of denial.

Comment: The goal is not exactly to convince die-hard Trump supporters, but more the probably relatively small still undecided middleground and those who can activate the home support base. One would chose partners that resonate with these groups specifically.

Answer (score 9):

Obama and Clinton are both two-term Presidents, with very high post-office approval ratings.  Here's a link, to a poll from 2023: [Popularity of Politicians](https://today.yougov.com/ratings/politics/popularity/politicians/all)

The most popular politicians in this survey are 1) Obama  2) Schwarzanegger 3) Carter 4) W. Clinton.  Well, Arnie is a Republican, and Carter is 99 years old and not doing public events.  So "who the heck do you expect him to associate with? Anthony Weiner?"

Comment: AOC slightly more popular than Trump. Ouch. I suspect that poll's base may be a little skewed, esp. since Kamala Harris is rated more popular too, but IIRC other polls found otherwise. https://www.newsweek.com/kamala-harris-matchup-against-donald-trump-1868650

Comment: @thegodsfromengineering - It could be—it is based on online polling, I think—but I don't a priori find that implausible. Both Ocasio-Cortez and Trump are polarizing figures that are generally viewed as partisan, particularly by the other party, but Trump has a multitude of *personal* vices to drag him down compared to Ocasio-Cortez.

Answer (score 6):

The question is based in a somewhat inaccurate premise—that the two figures mentioned have fallen in popularity since their terms and perhaps even are less popular than Biden. However, Barack Obama, like Bill Clinton and Ronald Reagan, left office with rising popularity. In Obama's case, several years later, [his retrospective job approval rating was higher than when he had left office](https://news.gallup.com/poll/508625/retrospective-approval-jfk-rises-trump.aspx), while Bill Clinton seems to be a little less popular now, but was [around as popular in 2018 as when he left office](https://news.gallup.com/poll/226994/obama-first-retrospective-job-approval-rating.aspx). A notable element of that polling is that almost all presidents, Clinton and Obama included, had higher post-presidency approval than their average approval during their presidency. In any case, both of those presidents seem to be more popular than Biden at the moment, with [his 39% approval rating](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/biden-approval-rating/) (and higher disapproval), so trying to create an association between a more popular figure and a less popular one to help the latter is basic public relations.

The really important figure in that data is the *partisan* approval, because these ex-presidents are not being brought out to convince Republicans, but rather to excite and motivate Democrats. While Clinton enjoys a 76% approval rating among Democrats, Obama has a very high 94% approval—on the same level as the partisan approval of John F. Kennedy. When [only 57% of a party's voters](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-tops-opponents-biden-hits-new-low-approval/story?id=106335244) would be satisfied with the incumbent as their party's candidate, trying to associate the incumbent with these relatively more popular figures is a predictable political strategy. In the case of Obama in particular, the former president continues to have very high approval among Black voters and particularly Black Democrats, while Biden's support [has been flagging somewhat](https://news.gallup.com/poll/609776/democrats-lose-ground-black-hispanic-adults.aspx); since Democratic strategists see Black voters as a key constituency, Obama's support could help arrest or reverse this tendency.